# how to replace number in a string that contains brackets in php

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a problem replacing the number in a string with a new number. The description is here. The problem is that when i upload a file it saves the file name in the same directory where the file is already found. Hence the server saves the file name appending `(1)` to the file name.

```
$file_name = 'Haller(1).jpg';
```

This is sample string i have put here.
Now what i need to do is this

```
$number = 5;
$file_name = 'Haller(1).jpg';
```

Output

```
$file_name = 'Haller(5).jpg';
```

How can i do this in php. I am too weak in regular expressions. Please help

Comment: i would surely research but i am in too hurry. thanks i will pay attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try preg_replace

```
preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '(' . $your_number_to_replace . ')', $your_file_name);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 5;
$file_name = 'Haller(1).jpg';

echo preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '(' . $number . ')', $file_name); // Haller(5).jpg
```

- `\d` match digit.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `preg_replace`

```
$number = 5;
$file_name = 'Haller(1).jpg'
$return = preg_replace("/\d/", $number, $file_name);
echo $return;
```

note that i have only placed `\d` since your requirement only have 1 number to be replaced. if your expecting a multi-digit number change it to `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php You can replace several values at a time

```
<?php
$patterns = array ('/(19|20)(\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/',
                   '/^\s*{(\w+)}\s*=/');
$replace = array ('\3/\4/\1\2', '$\1 =');
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, '{startDate} = 1999-5-27');
?>
```